# Fetch data from program and display them in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, electron, frontend

I'm working on a frontend interface using HTML/CSS/JS + Electron JS which will display games and hours played.

I found this https://www.gameplay-time-tracker.info/en/default.aspx to track the applications.

Is there a way to retrieve from the program the datas of each game and display them in HTML ?

Or is there any friendlier alterntive for application tracking for the web ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.gameplay-time-tracker.info/en/faq.aspx
question 16:

Question: I want to study raw data collected by this application
(to plot custom diagrams etc.).
Is there a way to export raw data to other software?

Answer: yes, there is. For versions prior to 3.0, you can open XML files in your user profile folder with Microsoft Excel.
For example, open “DailyStatistics.xml” to export gameplay times on a daily basis, open “Applications.xml” to export statistics of individual games.
Starting with version 3.0, you can fetch data from SQLite database file “GameplayTimeTracker.sqlite” (it is unprotected).
It can be done with SQLiteStudio (free software, excellent tool which I highly recommend).
Starting with version 3.0.2, you can export all applications and statistics to CSV files (comma-delimited, quoted).
These CSV files can be opened with Microsoft Excel or any other software supporting CSV file format.

so the answer looks like yes... but getting 'live' data as you play. I don't know... (but it would be a SQLite query it looks like if it is possible to query while it's open).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I didn't pay attention to the FAQ. Forthe "live" data I want it to be updated after X time. Is that possible ?

Comment: if you can at all get live data... the process of updating is just a setTimeout(function(){
fetch(PHPCODE},300) where the PHPCODE handles the sqlite query.

Comment: But the problem here is that I have to export each time data from the xml ?

Comment: it says it supports sqlite queries, that would be just a script you write to run and export the data each time you execute that script.

Comment: sooo interesting ! I'm very weak in PHP/MYSQL and only work with HTML/CSS/JS, do you have something that can help me getting started and perhaps achieve this objective ?

Comment: dani krossing on youtube has a great php/sql series. would recommend to get started with.